# What are my options for creating animated planets and stars in Godot 2D?

Tags: game-design, animation, godot, art

I'm creating a simple game / digital picture frame as a present. It is split into a picture scene and a planetary scene, which will have slight animations, date, time and maybe some messages.

The planetary scene will contain a sun in the center as well as the earth and a moon orbiting it. What are my options to animate the planets (comparable to [Kurzgesagt](https://www.youtube.com/@KurzgesagtDE) art style, which is considered `flat design` or `flat neon color illustration`. I'm looking for something which can be picked up rather easy and doesn't need to be too fancy, as I'd like to finalize it before Christmas.

I'm somewhat aware how Kurzgesagt does it: They design in Adobe Illustrator and animate in After Effects.

Is this feasible for a Godot Project?

I know one can create images and animations and flatten them in a Spritesheet. Would this be preferable or should I look into shaders?

I'm a programmer and don't know much about illustration or the possibilities one has in game design. Any helpful response is appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

The feasibility depends largely on your skills and expectations. Using Godot may have some complications.

Kurzgesagt uses SVG / vector art to get that smooth scaling art animation. Godot does not have direct SVG support. Rotating or scaling a sprite can look different than rotating or scaling vector art. Without more information, it's impossible to know if the results would be satisfactory for your slight animations. If you're sticking to sprites of simple geometric shapes (or things that can be built up from simple shapes) with solid colors (or maybe gradient fills), it could be fine.

You could do those operations in some other software & export the results. The results will likely look smoother, but it is going to add complexity to your workflow.

Godot does provide a [custom drawing](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/2d/custom_drawing_in_2d.html) option which can be used to make smooth looking shapes. I haven't used it and am not familiar with its performance. It does require you to describe things programmatically though; it is not a point and click solution.

Objectively, I would recommend looking at some basic Godot tutorials, in particular the official [Your first 2D game](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_2d_game/index.html) tutorial.  If you can imagine how you might take whatever it is you're trying to make in terms of that (or other) tutorials, then there's a much better chance that Godot will be feasible for your project and timeline.

Finally, keep in mind that a simple looking result does not mean that the behinds the scenes process is simple. Kurzgesagt has a video called [How to Make a Kurzgesagt Video in 1200 Hours](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFk0mgljtns). We cannot judge the whether or not your timeline is sufficient to learn to use a new engine with the hopes of achieving something that the engine isn't necessarily designed to support, especially given the lack of details in the expected results.